# Column changes FAB's position in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, floating-action-button

I have a problem where If I wrap my FABs placed a the end of a BottomNavigationBar in a Column, It changes their positions. I don't want to wrap it in a stack because than it is unclickable, I tried various ways to fix that, but none of them worked.

FAB 1:

```
Widget add(){
   return new FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: (){Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));},
    heroTag: 'btnAdd',
    child: new Icon(Icons.add),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    elevation: 0.0,
    splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
  );
}
```

FAB 2:

```
  Widget floatMain(){
    return new FloatingActionButton(
      heroTag: 'btnMain',
      child: new AnimatedIcon(
        icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
        progress: _animateIcon,
      ),
      tooltip: 'floatMain',
      onPressed: animate,
      backgroundColor: _buttonColor.value,
   );
 }
```

FAB Call:

```
floatingActionButton: new Container(
    child: new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          child: new Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, _translateButton.value - 56, 0.0),
            child: add(),
          ),
        ),
        floatMain(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked
```

So, if I wrap it in a Stack it works, but it doesn't work with a Column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only FAB button buttom right align. Inside column
Try it.

```
Expanded(
 child: Align(
alignment:FractionalOffset.bottomRight,
child: Padding(
 padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0), 
child: floatMain()//Your FAB widget here,
 ), 
), 
),
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, had to do some extra, but I got the logic.